# DocuSign - EnvelopeViews : createSender How to hide "send later" button next to the "continue" button

Tags: docusignapi

I tried with createSenderView api to get a senderView
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createsender/

According to the api description above, I set sendButtonAction = redirect to change the button on the right down corner from "send" to "continue".

But I found there was still a inverted triangle button next to the "continue" button, and when hang over the button, it will show up "send later".

I just wondering whether there is a parameter that can help me hide that inverted triangle button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you can disable "Send Later" for your entire account so that this never shows for anyone. This may work for you if you just don't use/need this feature and don't want it to ever show.

There's no feature right now that allows you to pick and choose when you want "Send Later" and when you don't. So it's all or nothing. If nothing works - you're good. If not - you may want so file an enhancement request with DocuSign.

Comment: Thank you Inbar for your answer! I am good with all or nothing.
Could you pls tell me where and how I can disable "Send Later" for the entire account?

Comment: You would need to contact customer support for this Arbor, It's not exposed to the users to make this type of change yet.